# Fast computation of eigenvalues of large Hermitian matrices

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, numerics, linear-algebra

I need to compute numerically all the eigenvalues of roughly $500$ large Hermitian matrices, $(5 \times 10^5) \times (5 \times 10^5)$).

At best, I can speed up my computation such that it takes almost twice the amount of time that I can reach on python using the numpy package.

I would like if such a difference can be in general further reduced, and the two performance can be similar, or there is a gap between mathematica an python that I cannot fill.

Comment: That's weird. I thought that both numpy and Mathematica link to the same library (ARPACK). Be sure to use `Method->"Arnoldi"`; see also documentation of `Eigenvalues`.

Comment: Oh thank you. I will try to do some tests on that. But so, on general ground, should I expect to reach the same performance with mathematica and python? thatnks!

Comment: Mathematica should perfom some additional copy operations for the transfer to and from the library in order to preserve immutability. But that should be negligible compared to the effort of computing the eigenvalues. Once the matrix is in the library (and the same options are uses), I see now reason why there should be a performance difference. Unfortunately, Mathematica provides only few suboptions for "Arnoldi" to tune it further. Moreover, I don't know to which version of ARPACK they link.

Comment: I see. Actually from the documentation it seems that Arnoldi method can be used only if we need few eigenvalues but I need all of them. Do you know whether I can overcome this problem?

Comment: Doh. Yeah, that is an issue. You can try to compute first and secand half of spectrum separately. Moreover, it just came to my mind that Mathematica might not link to the parallel version of ARPACK =/

Comment: I am now quite sure that Mathematica uses a parallel version. Still, the Arnoldi method is not _meant_ for computing all eigenvalues. I use to say: If you try to compute all eigenvalues of such a large matrix (and you expect them to be exact) then you are doing something wrong. However, I don't know what you need them for...

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately for what I am going to do all the eigenvalues are necessary (of course, I do not want the exact values of them).

Comment: Then I wish you all the best and good luck for your project. Btw.: I presumed that your matrix is sparse. Is it?

Comment: good point! they are sparse but when I try to get all the eigenvalues mathematica prefers to convert them to be dense

Comment: You may also try `Method -> "FEAST"`. I have to say that I have really few experience with that method.

Comment: Yes, is what I am trying now. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!